# matplotlib line with different color depending on other variable

Tags: matplotlib

I want to plot a time-series using matplotlib and plot. However, I want the line color to change depending on another discrete time-series.

```
income = [5000, 5005, 5010, 6000, 6060, 6120, 7000]
job = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2]
```

I tried something like:

```
plt.plot(income, c=job, cmap='RdBu')
```

but that leads to 'Line2D' object has no property 'cmap'. I also tried:

```
plt.scatter(range(0, len(income)), income, c=job, cmap='RdBu')
```

does not give the lines which is also not ideal. Is there any way to make a figure like the one below [created in Matlab] in Matplotlib?

[image]

Comment: This problem has been asked and answered multiple times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think colormap is useful for continuous data. For discrete it is better to use discrete color list. Thus, you can pair color to type variable:

**Code:**

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors


income = np.array([5000, 5005, 5010, 6000, 6060, 6120, 7000])
x = np.arange(len(y))
job = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2]).astype('int')

# iterate over zipped job and color
for j, c in zip(job, colors.TABLEAU_COLORS):
    plt.plot(x[job == j], income[job == j], 'o-', c=c)

plt.show()
```

**Plot:**

[image: plot]

I used `TABLEAU_COLORS` but you can find another color list [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/color/named_colors.html) if you wish.